# Non parametric version of Hotelling's $T^2$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, robust

Is there a non parametric version for Hotelling's $T^2$ test? Namely, the one group test for location (not the two group).

Comment: Do you mean the largest root of a noncentral Wishart matrix? Like the solution to $|\lambda \Omega - Z'Z|=0$?

Comment: @Hirek: I want a test for the location of a multivariate symmetric (exchangeable?) distribution without the Gaussianity assumption.

Comment: OK so your null hypothesis is the mean I gather. This one's hard because it is constructed as two Gaussians sandwhiching a Wishart matrix. Some terms to look up in the Journal of Multivariate Analysis or elsewhere would be central limit theorem (effect), T2 test, non-parametric etc. I got this http://methodology.psu.edu/media/techreports/13-124.pdf and also http://www.researchgate.net/publication/260806345_Prediction_of_Surface_Ozone_Exceedance_Days_Using_PCA_with_Non-parametric_T2_Control_Limit The first seems to have what you look for. Also search for non-parametric Bartlett decomp..

Comment: PS @JohnRos if you find either of my comments helpful, or the links in my previous one for that matter, you can upvote them as well! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

All it took was finding the right keywords to google.
After finding and reading a bunch of papers, I found [1] to be an excellent reference with several non-parametric versions of Hotelling's one-sample $T^2$ test.

[1] Oja, Hannu, and Ronald H. Randles. “Multivariate Nonparametric Tests.” Statistical Science 19, no. 4 (November 1, 2004): 598–605.

Comment: Here's the DOI link for that paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/088342304000000558